# Migrate JwtAuthentication to Asp.Core 2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Getting a depreciated error when moving from 1.0 to 2.0

What do I do to enable automatic authentication and replace this with the 2.0 equivalent

```
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2.0, authentication configuration has moved into `ConfigureServices`. The reason for this move was to get rid of complications of multiple authentication schemes trying to authenticate the user if your set up was not proper (I think). There is a BIG discussion on this somewhere on the ASPNET Identity github repo if you want to read about it. In your case, you will need to move this to the `ConfigureServices` method.

Example:

```
    services.AddAuthentication("idSrv")
            .AddCookie("Cookies",(options) => {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect("idSrv",(options) =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.Authority = "https://foobar.com";
                options.ClientId = "clientname";
                options.ClientSecret = "clientsecret";
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
                options.SecurityTokenValidator = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler {
                    InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                };
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    RoleClaimType = "role"
                };
            });
```

1. The param name in `AddAuthentication` is the `DefaultAuthenticationScheme`.
2. In your case, the default will be the JWT scheme with whatever options instead of OpenIdConnect as in the above example, for instance:

   ```
               .AddJwtBearer("JWT",options =>
               {
                   ...
                   ...
                   options.SaveToken = true;
                   options.TokenValidationParameters = ...
               });
   ```
3. Then in the Configure method you will just call `app.UseAuthentication`
4. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?tabs=aspnetcore2x) & [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x) for more info.

Also, going from 1.0 to 2.0 is a brave move :) I wouldn't. I moved from 1.0.x to 1.1.x and now moving to 2. Good Luck!

Comment: Great Meqeet, Thanks!